# JS: .map() with async callback but missing return statement

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Take these two code snippets using `.map()` and `Promise.all()` to resolve promises in parallel.

Snippet 1:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const asyncTask = (name) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    const result = `resolved: ${name}`
    console.log({ result })
    resolve(result)
  }, 1000));
};

(async () => {
  console.log('start');

  const promises = myArray.map((value) => {
    return asyncTask(`task-${value}`);
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log('end');
})();
```

Snippet 2:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const asyncTask = (name) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    const result = `resolved: ${name}`
    console.log({ result })
    resolve(result)
  }, 1000));
};

(async () => {
  console.log('start');

  const promises = myArray.map(async (value) => {
    await asyncTask(`task-${value}`);
  });
  
  await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log('end');
})();
```

Both snippets do exactly the same. My understanding was that Snippet 2 would *not* await anything since the callback in `.map()` is **lacking a return statement** therefore `promises` would be of type `Promise<void>[]` . Turns out  `await Promise.all(promises)` still awaits all the promises from the callback instead of resolving immediately. Why is that?

Tried many different variations of the above code. I expect snippet 2 to not `await` but resolve immediately logging the following:

```
> 'start'
> 'end'
> *result of promises*
```

instead of (actual):

```
> 'start'
> *result of promises*
> 'end'
```

**EDIT: The accepted answer clarifies the issue but I want to emphasize that you shouldn't write code in this way. Neither the accepted answer nor Snippet 2 represent idiomatic ways of working with promises.**

Comment: "*Snippet 2 would not await anything since the callback in .map() is lacking a return statement therefore promises would be of type Promise<void>[]*" promises are still promises. Awaiting a promise still awaits the promise. The difference is that one resolves to an undefined (or `void`) the other will have a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That lack of a `return` statement means the function does an implicit `return undefined` at the end of the function. And since that function is `async` it returns a `Promise<undefined>`.

But this Promise only resolves when the function has finished; which you delay by `await`ing asyncTask.

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const asyncTask = (name) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    const result = `resolved: ${name}`
    console.log({ result })
    resolve(result)
  }, 1000));
};

(async () => {
  console.log('start');

  const promises = myArray.map(async (value) => {
    /* removed await */ asyncTask(`task-${value}`);
  });
  
  await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log('end');
})();
```

Comment: no `await`? then no `async`.

Comment: @Mulan that would have changed the return type of that function. My point here is that it's this specific `await` which causes the behavior that OP did not expect, not the fact that the function is `async`. Yes, the `async` is now pointless, but it's not OPs issue.

Comment: Removing `await` ***radically changes the semantics of the code***! It means all the promises created by the function being async are rather useless since each only does a fire and forget of `asyncTask`. Thus `await Promise.all(promises);` doesn't actually do anything worthwhile. It's a roundabout way to wait for the `.map()` execution to finish *without* waiting for any `asyncTask` to finish.

Comment: @VLAZ I know that, but I don't think that's important to OPs question. Going by the expected result I'd say OP tried to produce such a fire-and forget situation and was wondering why his code did not behave that way. As I see it, OP didn't make the connection that awaiting inside an `async function` will delay the resolution of the returned Promise even if this function has no explicit `return`.

Comment: With the widespread misunderstanding of promises I believe it's plain irresponsible to promote useless promise handling with the suggestion to just remove the `await` but still heat up the CPU with some noop ops. We already see plenty of promises misuse. Encouraging more of that (by not discouraging it nor explaining why it's useless) is counterproductive.

Comment: @VLAZ This post together with your comment above clarified it for me. To be clear I am not trying to write code like this and would not encourage anybody to do so. It was more the case that I saw code like this and thought there was something to fix. I'll accept this answer and add a note that this would not be the idiomatic way to use promises.